# Noun with Meaning Related to "Confidential"

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't seem to remember the word (a noun) to fill in the blank space:

"Please keep this matter confidential" is equivalent to "I'd appreciate your _____ in the matter."

Comment: How about "I'd appreciate your confidence in the matter"?

Comment: The idiom is `in confidence`. It will have to be rephrased to something like `Can I tell you something in confidence?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I'd appreciate your **[discretion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discretion)** in the matter."

> The quality of behaving or speaking in such a way as to avoid causing offence or revealing confidential information:

[Oxford]

Comment: @DanBron: Hats off for sportsmanship!

Comment: Very good one :)!

Comment: What happened here?

Comment: @LCW: We both posted the same answer simultaneously. I was a fraction of a second earlier, so Dan Bron voluntarily took down his answer. Now I'm 50 up, thanks to him.

Comment: Apparently great minds think alike! I have experienced this on other SE sites too - it would be good if SE can implement a feature that shows the if and how many users are composing an answer. Of course, this comment belongs in Mother Meta....

Comment: By the way, could you take a look at my comment under the question? I just looked up that word and wanted to see if it sounds strange at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I would appreciate your *trustworthiness* in this matter.
> I am relying on your *trustworthiness* in this matter. I hope you are a *reliable* confidant.

**[trust·wor·thy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trustworthiness)**  (trŭst′wûr′thē)

- adj. trust·wor·thi·er, trust·wor·thi·est
- Warranting trust; reliable. See Synonyms at reliable.
- trust′wor′thi·ly adv.
- trust′wor′thi·ness n.

*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.*